How to use a `Vec<&'a dyn Trait>` (A collection of references to trait object) across threads?
I am trying to use a Vec<&'a dyn Trait> (A collection of references to trait object) across threads. This is my code, which I think is self-explanatory with the comments:
use std::{
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
    thread::{self, JoinHandle},
};

// This is basis for some trait objects
trait Startable {
    fn start(&self);
}

// A runner has a collection of references to these trait objects
// - ...which is behind a Mutex, so it could be concurrently accessed
// - ...and aslo behind an Arc, so it could be safely cloned and sent to other threads.
struct Runner<'a> {
    startables: Arc<Mutex<Vec<&'a (dyn Startable + Sync)>>>,
}

impl<'a> Runner<'a> {
    fn start_all(&mut self) -> JoinHandle<()> {
        // Get a copy so it can be moved to other thread.
        let startables = self.startables.clone(); // ERROR!

        // Runner starts a new thread where it expects to use the
        // collection of references to these trait objects.
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let startables = startables.lock().unwrap();

            // Do something with the startables, e.g.:
            for startable in startables.iter() {
                startable.start();
            }
        });

        handle
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut runner = Runner {
        startables: Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![/* trait objects */])),
    };
    let handle = runner.start_all();
    let _ = handle.join();
}

This produces the following error:
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of method
  --> src/main.rs:21:26
   |
18 | impl<'a> Runner<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
19 |     fn start_all(&mut self) -> JoinHandle<()> {
   |                  --------- `self` is a reference that is only valid in the method body
20 |         // Get a copy so it can be moved to other thread.
21 |         let startables = self.startables.clone();
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                          |
   |                          `self` escapes the method body here
   |                          argument requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`
   |
   = note: requirement occurs because of the type `Mutex<Vec<&dyn Startable + Sync>>`, which makes the generic argument `Vec<&dyn Startable + Sync>` invariant
   = note: the struct `Mutex<T>` is invariant over the parameter `T`

I don't quite understand why T in Mutex<T> being invariant becomes a problem. Because, if the collection was Vec<Box<(dyn Startable + Sync + Send)>>, this compiles without a problem:
//... other definitions as before
struct Runner {
    // Only change is in this line:
    startables: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Box<(dyn Startable + Sync + Send)>>>>,
}

impl Runner {
    fn start_all(&mut self) -> JoinHandle<()> {
        let startables = self.startables.clone(); // WORKS!

        let start_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
            let startables = startables.lock().unwrap();

            // ...
        });

        start_thread
    }
}

But I want to use references to trait objects across threads, and not require 'static lifetimes. What am I missing here? How can I better specify a lifetime such that original code compiles? Or is there any form of marker I can use to indicate that the collection lives beyond the lifetime of the start_all method?

The question is how can the compiler see this is safe? Only with a 'static lifetime bound! And for references, that means a 'static lifetime.

@cafce25, so if I ask it in a different way: How can I send a collection of across threads?

For arbitrary threads they must be 'static! The compiler doesn't know how long the threads run but the references must be valid for the entire runtime of every thread that can access it thus the only lifetime that allows arbitrary lengths must be chosen.

Of course you can achieve arbitrary lifetime with a reference counted allocation (Arc) as well.

The only other way would be if you could somehow use scoped threads to achieve what you want. But that would likely require changing the architecture of your program.

Where do the underlying objects you're storing references to live? That location has to be 'static to outlive the thread using its data, and then you might as well remove the lifetime from Runner and have it store &'static dyn....

@BallpointBen they currently live in main, but it could be arbitrary. Yeah, now I see the problem.

A similar error can be produced with much simpler code:
fn start_all(reference: &u8) {
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("{reference}");
    });
}

fn main() {
    start_all(&5);
}

Which produces:
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
1 |   fn start_all(reference: &u8) {
  |                ---------  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
  |                |
  |                `reference` is a reference that is only valid in the function body
2 | /     std::thread::spawn(move || {
3 | |         println!("{reference}");
4 | |     });
  | |      ^
  | |      |
  | |______`reference` escapes the function body here
  |        argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0521`.

So, (despite the question) dyn, Vec, and (despite the original error message) Mutex and (in)variance are not necessarily relevant.
The only lifetime for reference that would make this code compile is 'static, as any other lifetime might expire before the spawned thread runs.
Using Box<_> instead of &_ also works, as Box conveys ownership that lasts until, in the original case, all arc-references to the Arc containing it are dropped. One of those arc-references is transferred to the spawned thread.
For completeness, note that using scoped threads allows it to compile:
fn start_all(reference: &u8) {
    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|| {
            println!("{reference}");
        });
    });
}

However, these threads are joined immediately so they wouldn't run concurrently with the caller of start_all (which can't return a JoinHandle). In principle, you could spawn a scoped thread per startable task to make the tasks concurrent with each other.

The function in the OP returns a JoinHandle that isn't possible with a thread::scope, if it wasn't required this question would be a duplicate of How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread? anyways.

@cafce25 The question implied not one but two requirements 1) non-'static lifetime reference, not 'static or box 2) normal threads, not scoped threads. These requirements are in contradiction; at least one must be relaxed for the code to compile. I explained both, including how each could be relaxed independently of the other, to solve the problem. Yes, relaxing the normal thread requirements has the consequence of not returning a JoinHandle. In the original code, the JoinHandle was immediately joined, but perhaps the actual use-case does something different.

Also, my answer was intended to help address the concern about Mutex and (in)variance, in a way that no existing comment or answer here does.

Thanks for simplifying the case. This explains the issue much better. For my own use case scoped threads isn't possible, because I wanted concurrency.

Thanks to @cafce25's comment, I was able to find an answer that worked for me.

For arbitrary threads they must be 'static! The compiler doesn't know how long the threads run but the references must be valid for the entire runtime of every thread that can access it thus the only lifetime that allows arbitrary lengths must be chosen.

This is what I came up with:
struct Runner {
    startables: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Arc<dyn Startable + Send + Sync>>>>,
}
/* rest of the code as before */

At least for my case, atomic reference-count is as good as a reference.

In case you need mutable items in the collection:
trait Startable {
    // Now, start takes a mutable reference
    fn start(&mut self);
}

struct Runner {
    // Each item in the collection is behind a Mutex
    startables: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Arc<Mutex<dyn Startable + Send + Sync>>>>>,
}

impl Runner {
    fn start_all(&mut self) -> JoinHandle<()> {
        let startables = self.startables.clone();

        let start_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
            let startables = startables.lock().unwrap();

            for startable in startables.iter() {
                // You need to lock the Mutex in order to mutate items
                startable.lock().unwrap().start();
            }
        });

        start_thread
    }
}

